# does birt runtime 4.5 need java 1.7?

Tags: birt

I just downloaded birt runtime birt-runtime-4.5.0-20150609.zip and installed under JBoss.

the following is the env info:

Java version: 1.6.0_10,Sun Microsystems Inc.

OS-System: SunOS 5.10,sparcv9

jboss.home.dir: /opt/jboss_dist/jboss-portal-2.6.2.GA

sun.arch.data.model: 64

even the Jboss we are using is old, but we could run birt 4.4.2 successfully.

When I install birt 4.5, I got java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError. Is birt 4.5 compiled using java 1.7? The pre-requisite for birt 4.5 is java 1.6. What should I do to fix it?

2016-01-29 03:08:19,486 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] AbstractWebContainer.parseWebAppDescriptors, End
2016-01-29 03:08:19,524 DEBUG [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer] Using session cookies default setting
2016-01-29 03:08:25,533 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/birt]] Exception sending con
text initialized event to listener instance of class org.eclipse.birt.report.listener.ViewerServletContextListener
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/Platform : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1817)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:872)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.WebAppClassLoader.findClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1325)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.ServicePlatform.getExtensionRegistry(ServicePlatform.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.ServicePlatform.createFactoryObject(ServicePlatform.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:297)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform.createFactoryObject(Platform.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.setEngineContext(ReportEngineService.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.setContext(BirtViewerReportService.java:1023)
        at org.eclipse.birt.report.listener.ViewerServletContextListener.contextInitialized(ViewerServletContextListener.jav
a:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3854)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4359)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:761)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:553)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor148.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5310)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor144.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:301)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:104)
        at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
        at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
        at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
        at $Proxy200.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor127.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)

Thanks, Helen

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, as mentionned [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Eclipse_4.5_.28Mars.29):

> A Java 7 JRE/JDK is required for all Mars package downloads based on
>   Eclipse 4.5. Information concerning tested configurations for Eclipse
>   4.5 is provided here.

The BIRT engine 4.5 itself is still compiled with a java 6 compliance but many eclipse libraries require java 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

BIRT has some dependencies which are given http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/. They have specifically mentioned only Java 1.7 JDK/JRE as a pre-requisite but not higher version of JDK/JRE. The latest BIRT Runtime Release Build is: 4.8.0 which is compatible with Java 1.7 JDK/JRE.